# How to implement tab panel in product page for magento enterprise version?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

I want to add tab panel in product page. currently my tab is https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLw7Q.png

so please advise me

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/

Comment: @RkRathod i do not want custom tab panel... I want default tab panel